# search input field shrinks on user engagement on android

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a curious situation when rendering a section of my [website](http://www.gastromend.com/shop.php) using `android` mobile devices.

The search input field on my website shrinks as soon as the user commences typing and the page seems to break its stylesheet constraints temporarily.

I am perplexed, as this anomaly does not occur in `iOS` and I cannot seem to produce the bug using any web inspector when in responsive mode.

To replicate the problem:

1. Open my [website shop.php](http://www.gastromend.com/shop.php) page on your android device.
2. Open the hamburger nav and type into the search input field.

Any steering would be appreciated as I have looked high and low online to resolve without success.

> hamburger nav code - html

```
<div id="menu-icon">


    <span class="first"></span><span class="second"></span><span class="third"></span>


</div>




<nav>









      <form class="search" method="get" action="results.php" autocomplete="off"> 


          <div>   

            <input type="search" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="none" spellcheck="false" size="22" maxlength="22" name="searchterm" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9\s]{0,25}" placeholder="search rowena mae products">

          </div>  


       </form>






          <ul>



                <?php

                      get_categories_within_hamburger();

                ?>





           </ul>


  </nav>
```

> hamburgernav.css

```
@media screen 
  and (device-width: 360px) 
  and (device-height: 640px) 
  and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2) 
  and (orientation: portrait) {








      nav {

        width: 100%;

        /*width: 360px;*/

      }  




    #menu-icon {

        top: 18px;

    }



    nav ul li a {
        float: none;
        padding: 8px;
        display: block;
        color: antiquewhite;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
        font-size: 16px;
    }



    .search input {
        width: 100%;
        background: #FDFBF6;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 16px;
        height: 38px;


    }




}
```